# Game rotation limits

Tags: game-engine

I'm having a problem keeping my playing field inside my box. Is there a way to make my box a rotation limit/boundary?

If you notice the x-axis and y-axis can rotate beyond the bottom of the box. Also if you make "extreme" rotations the playing field seems to rotate on the z-axis and then conflicts with the outside portions of the box.

[image: Z-axis out of wack]

[image: Past the box y-axis]

[image: Past the box x-axis]

Comment: It looks like you want to turn the board. Why not just play predefined animations (actions)?

Comment: will that work considering that I'm hoping to add multiple levels once this is finalized? Or do I have to pre-define every level? Mainly because every board will be different. Sorry for the not so understanding...like I said before...I'm very new to blender. Thanks to my class it's the only reason that I have heard of it. I like it so far just need to get better. Thanks for the advice as well as future advice.

Comment: I tried adding a container to another layer. Made this container "passive" and a "mesh" but to no avail it still allows the playing field to pass through......Any Advice???? I'm at a total loss on this and I'm sure it is something so minute that I'm just overlooking or overthinking it....Thanks